# moving animated sprite along with a path in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, animation, cocos2d-x

I want to move an animated sprite along with a path(i mean std::vector < cocos2d::Point > st).

this is my code.

```
std::vector<cocos2d::Point> st;
Vector< FiniteTimeAction * > fta;
.......
while (!st.empty()) {
    auto des = st.back();
    auto moveAction = MoveTo::create(des.distance(currentPos) / 34, des);
    ...

    auto aniForever = RepeatForever::create(moveAnimation);
    auto seq = Sequence::create(moveAction, CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_0(Barbarian::stopAnimation, this, aniForever)), NULL);
    auto spw = Spawn::create(aniForever, seq, NULL);
    fta.pushBack(spw);

    .....
    st.pop_back();
}

auto seq = Sequence::create(fta);
sprite->runAction(seq);
```

In that way, when moveAction finished, it will call stopAnimation to stop aniForever.
stopAnimation is below

```
void CharacterBase::stopAnimation(cocos2d::RepeatForever *ani) {
CCLOG("STOP ANIMATION");
sprite->stopAction(ani);  }
```

but i found some problem with my code. the sprite is moving without animation.

can someone tell me why and find a solution for me ?
Thank you all

Comment: the spawn is superfluous, you can just do runAction(aniForever) next to running seq. Please also post the code where you create moveAnimation.

Answer (score 1):

You code is not complete, but it seems that you should separate animation action and movement action. They can run at the same time. Try this pseudo-code:

```
//when you start moving
auto moveAnimation = createMoveAnimation();
sprite->runAction(moveAnimation);//start play move animation now

Vector< FiniteTimeAction * > fta;
while (!st.empty()) {
    auto des = st.back();
    auto moveAction = MoveTo::create(des.distance(currentPos) / 34, des);
    fta.pushBack(moveAction );
    st.pop_back();
}
auto endAnimation = CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_0(Barbarian::stopAnimation, this, aniForever)//after movement stop movement animation
fta.pushBack(endAnimation);

//so far, you have created a list of moving actions and a stop animation call at the end
auto seq = Sequence::create(fta);
sprite->runAction(seq);//let the sprite move
```